# Make default statement not exit (C)

Tags: c, input, menu, integer, switch-statement

I am a beginner in C programming and I'm trying to do basic stuff. I'm trying to create a simple menu using a `switch` statement like this:

```
int disp(){
    int check;
    while(check!=1){
        int choose;
        printf("1 \n");
        printf("5quit\n");
        scanf("%d", &choose);

        switch(choose)
        {
            case 1:func1();
            break;

            case 5: check = 1;
            break;

            default:
                printf("wrong input");
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

However, when either `default` or `case 1` happen, I want to make it still loop the menu until a good input is made. For example, if I enter random stuff like "asdf", the program should say "wrong input" and then display the menu again and wait for user input. And if user enters "1", the program will run `func1` and then go back to the menu and wait for the user to input a choice.

Currently, when a wrong input happens it just shuts down the program instead of displaying the menu again, and I don't know how to solve that.

Comment: Second line `int check;` third line `while(check!=1)` - uninitialised variable. Please take note of your compiler warnings, at the very least.

Comment: Your `return 0;` is in the wrong place - move it to the last line of `main()`.

Comment: My compilar doesnt display any warnings/errors with this code.using Codeblocks

Comment: Time to enable them?

Comment: I just reformatted the code to make @PaulR's comment stand out better. Watch your indentation. If you follow a regular pattern of indentation it will make it easier for you to spot little mistakes like the return inside the loop. And definitely [visit the compiler options to turn up](http://www.codeblocks.org/docs/main_codeblocks_en3.html#x3-270001.11.6) the compiler's reporting. Warnings allow the code to compile and run, but are marking something that has consequences you should be aware of. Maybe you really wanted to do something odd, that's why they are only warnings, but if you didn't...

Comment: Good question by the way. It provided what you wanted, what you got, and all the code needed to find the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `return 0` statement is inside of your `while` loop.  Move it down one line, outside of the loop.

This is one reason why proper indentation is important.

At this point, entering in non-numeric input results in an infinite loop because `scanf` isn't reading in anything.  To remedy this, you call `getchar` in a loop after calling `scanf` to flush the buffer:

```
int c;
scanf(" %d", &choose);
while ((c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n');
```

Comment: thank you,however now when I enter a wrong input my menu is displaying millions of times without waiting for the user input(infinite loop)?

Comment: @sageb. Insert the following code after calling `scanf()` to flush the input buffer: `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n');`

Comment: thank you! solved my two problems! But I am not sure of what is EOF and I dont understand the statement " c  !=" it checks if getchar is not equal to..nothing?

Comment: @sageb.  EOF is -1.  It's a special value that gets returned at the end on a stream.  The `while` loop keeps reading until `getchar` returns either a newline or the special EOF value.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct and close to what you want

```
// Use a proper formatting standard to improve readability
int disp() {
    int check = 0;    // Initialize the loop variable
    while (check != 1) {
        int choose;
        printf("1 \n");
        printf("5quit\n");
        scanf("%d\n", &choose);    // Ask the scanf to swallow the newline

        switch(choose) {
        case 1:
            func1();
            break;
        case 5:
            check = 1;
            break;
        default:
            printf("wrong input");
        }
    }
    return 0;    // Pull the statement out of the loop
}
```

**EDIT**: Since you are providing invalid input intentionally, it's better to check the return value of `scanf` to avoid errors.